# Republishing react-bootstrap component

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create an npm package that contains a wrapped react-bootstrap component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Spinner } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './LoadingSpinner.css';

const LoadingSpinner = props => {
    return (
        <div className={(!props.hide ? 'loading-spinner-background' : 'd-none') }>
            <Spinner animation="border" variant="primary" className='loading-spinner'/>
        </div>
    )
}

export {LoadingSpinner}
```

It packages OK, but when I try to use it, I get several errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at useContext (http://localhost:3001/portal/static/js/bundle.js:101810:31)
    at useBootstrapPrefix (http://localhost:3001/portal/static/js/bundle.js:70822:63)
```

and in the console several warnings like this:

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

If I change the reference to `<Spinner />` to something like `<div>spinner</div>`, it works.

New to packaging react components as npm packages, so I have probably missed something basic... A pointer to where someone has done something similar would be really useful.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "abc",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "README.md"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "webpack": "^5.78.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0"
  }
}
```

and .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Root cause was that i was using `npm link` - which in addition to linking the package into my main project, was also linking the `node_modules` directory - causing the components in the package to use a different instance of React than than the main project. It works if you load via npm registry, because only the dist files come down. Looking for a better dev solution, but at least got to the bottom of it.